# how to set the range

Tags: excel, vba

Please correct the following:

```
Dim FirstCellRow As Integer
FirstCellRow = 2

Dim LastCellRow As Integer
LastCellRow = 50

Dim FirstCell As Range
FirstCell = Cells(FirstCellRow, "G")

Dim LastCell As Range
LastCell = Cells(LastCellRow, "G")

Dim Data As Range
Set Data = Range(FirstCell:LastCell)
```

I don't want to use this feature: **set Data = Range("G2:G52")**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim FirstCellRow As Integer
FirstCellRow = 2

Dim LastCellRow As Integer
LastCellRow = 50

Dim FirstCell As Range
Set FirstCell = Cells(FirstCellRow, "G")

Dim LastCell As Range
Set LastCell = Cells(LastCellRow, "G")

Dim Data As Range

'You can use 3 type mothod
Set Data = Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
Set Data = Range("G" & FirstCellRow, "G" & LastCellRow)
Set Data = Range("G" & FirstCellRow & ":" & "G" & LastCellRow)
```